# Why is my compiled program zoomed in?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I designed the gui and program in Visual Studio 2015.  For some reason the compiled program looks different than the gui in the debug.  The gui appears to be zoomed in and it's making the text all blurry.  I have no idea what's causing this.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONGGZ.png)

Comment: You’re not using 100% scaling (96 DPI). That’s what’s causing this. What do you want to achieve now? Non-blurry text? A program that ignores scaling?

Comment: I was able to find the problem thanks to your comment, the problem was a computer setting, not in my software since I'd never set it to be scalable.  Thank you.